# Xamarin: No iOS Class in add new item for Visual Studio 2015

Tags: ios, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I am following the steps in the Windows Hello,iOS example at

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/hello,_iOS/hello,iOS_quickstart/

When I get to step 18, there is no iOS class to choose from. See my screen (https://i.stack.imgur.com/fT1r8.jpg). Look at the image in step 18 and you will see I am missing iOS. All other steps work without issues (connecting to Xmarin, selecting an iPhone project, choosing iPhone6 format etc). The tools to connect to my Mac work, I can launch the simulator etc.

I have uninstalled Xamarin 3 times now and rebooted in between. I am at a complete loss here. I followed all of the instructions on how to do a complete removal and clean install. Still no luck. How can I add iOS to this menu?

I am running Windows 10 latest updates and VS 2015 Pro inside a Parallels VM under OS X 10.11.2. Downloaded the latest Xamarin from website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone from Xamarin support got back to me. It appears to be a documentation issue and they are notifying the docs group. When I click "Add Item", I do not see an iOS section but you don't need to have one. The C# Class template under code will do just fine. In step 18, you can ignore the iOS tree and just go straight to Code and then C# Class. See the attached image to see the differences.

[image: Config differences between Xamarin docs and install on VS 2015]

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Xamarin on Visual Studio for a while now, Mac seems to have a lot less issues.
But you need to do 3 things :

1. Install Xamarin.iOS on Mac host, and activate
2. Configure your Mac host ( I recommend trying a sample iOS app using Xamarin studio at this point )
3. If all goes well, Install Xamarin for Visual Studio, and activate, and connect to your mac host

For more detailed instructions, you can see this :
[Xamarin Getting Started with visual studio](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/introduction_to_xamarin_ios_for_visual_studio/)

Comment: I have never used Xamarin on VS. This is a brand new install.

I have installed Xamarin.iOS on my Mac and I connected Visual Studio to my Xamarin on the Mac. All of that works perfectly fine. I simply don't get the iOS Class option to complete step 18. How can I manually install these classes???

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps, but is your startup project set as the iOS one ?

Comment: I only have one project which is the one built from Hello iOS. My install of VS 2015 is also fresh so it has never had anything else configured. Where do those items come from in the "Add New Item" dialog? Clearly you have an installed and online section so you must be able to populate that window somehow. Is there a command line I can run to force it to do this?

Comment: My experience with Xamarin says that sometimes if you restart, or even uninstall and reinstall, problems might just go away . Can you give that a shot ? especially if you happen to have installed Xamarin before Visual Studio

Comment: I re-installed everything and same problem.

I got someone from Xamarin support to look at this even though I have no support contract. We found the bug when I showed them my screen. It's purely a documentation error. You can ignore the iOS section and just go under Code.

If this helps others, can you upvote my answer? Thanks for your help as well.

Comment: Glad they were able to help, and sorry I couldn't , +1 for pointing out the difference with screenshots